# File path into JSON data structure

Tags: json, perl

I'm doing a disk space report that uses `File::Find` to collect cumulative sizing in a directory tree.

What I get (easily) from `File::Find` is the directory name.

e.g.:

```
/path/to/user/username/subdir/anothersubdir/etc
```

I'm running `File::Find` to collect sizes beneath:

```
/path/to/user/username
```

And build a cumulative size report of the directory and each of the subdirectories.

What I've currently got is:

```
while ( $dir_tree ) {
   %results{$dir_tree} += $blocks * $block_size;
   my @path_arr = split ( "/", $dir_tree ); 
   pop ( @path_arr );
   $dir_tree = join ( "/", @path_arr ); 
}
```

(And yes, I know that's not very nice.).

The purpose of doing this is so when I `stat` each file, I add it's size to the current node and each parent node in the tree.

This is sufficient to generate:

```
username,300M
username/documents,150M
username/documents/excel,50M
username/documents/word,40M
username/work,70M
username/fish,50M,
username/some_other_stuff,30M
```

But I'd like to now turn that in to JSON more like this:

```
{ 
    "name" : "username",
    "size" : "307200",
    "children" : [
        { 
            "name" : "documents",
            "size" : "153750",
            "children" : [
                  { 
                      "name" : "excel",
                      "size" : "51200"
                   }, 
                   {
                       "name" : "word",
                       "size" : "81920"
                   }
             ]
         }
    ]
}
```

That's because I'm intending to do a D3 visualisation of this structure - loosely based on [D3 Zoomable Circle Pack](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/pack-hierarchy.html)

So my question is this - what is the neatest way to collate my data such that I can have cumulative (and ideally non cumulative) sizing information, but populating a hash hierarchically.

I was thinking in terms of a 'cursor' approach (and using `File::Spec` this time):

```
use File::Spec; 
my $data;
my $cursor = \$data; 
foreach my $element ( File::Spec -> splitdir ( $File::Find::dir ) ) {
   $cursor -> {size} += $blocks * $block_size;
   $cursor = $cursor -> {$element} 
}
```

Although... that's not quite creating the data structure I'm looking for, not least because we basically have to search by hash key to do the 'rolling up' part of the process.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Edit - more complete example of what I have already:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
use Data::Dumper;

my $block_size = 1024;

sub collate_sizes {
    my ( $results_ref, $starting_path ) = @_;
    $starting_path =~ s,/\w+$,/,;
    if ( -f $File::Find::name ) {
        print "$File::Find::name isafile\n";
        my ($dev,   $ino,     $mode, $nlink, $uid,
            $gid,   $rdev,    $size, $atime, $mtime,
            $ctime, $blksize, $blocks
        ) = stat($File::Find::name);

        my $dir_tree = $File::Find::dir;
        $dir_tree =~ s|^$starting_path||g;
        while ($dir_tree) {
            print "Updating $dir_tree\n";
            $$results_ref{$dir_tree} += $blocks * $block_size;
            my @path_arr = split( "/", $dir_tree );
            pop(@path_arr);
            $dir_tree = join( "/", @path_arr );
        }
    }
}

my @users = qw ( user1 user2 );

foreach my $user (@users) {
    my $path = "/home/$user";
    print $path;
    my %results;
    File::Find::find(
        {   wanted   => sub { \&collate_sizes( \%results, $path ) },
            no_chdir => 1
        },
        $path
    );
    print Dumper \%results;

    #would print this to a file in the homedir - to STDOUT for convenience
    foreach my $key ( sort { $results{$b} <=> $results{$a} } keys %results ) {
       print "$key => $results{$key}\n";
    }
}
```

And yes - I know this isn't portable, and does a few somewhat nasty things. Part of what I'm doing here is trying to improve on that. (But currently it's a Unix based homedir structure, so that's fine).

Comment: Can you add a complete example that I can lazily copy/paste please?

Comment: OK, bear with me. Will have to trim my script down to size a little.

Comment: OK. Added a minimal example. (It omits a lot of junk, like some of the unit formatting and different summary outputs).

Comment: Seems like a pretty straight-forward approach.

Comment: Yes. But doesn't export to JSON very well at all.

Comment: Some minor notes: don't follow symlinks, which might put you above where you started. I've only made that mistake like 50 times. And, File::Spec has bits to canonicalize and break apart directories. Good luck, :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do your own dir scanning instead of using File::Find, you naturally get the right structure.

```
sub _scan {
   my ($qfn, $fn) = @_;
   my $node = { name => $fn };

   lstat($qfn)
      or die $!;

   my $size   = -s _;
   my $is_dir = -d _;

   if ($is_dir) {
      my @child_fns = do {
         opendir(my $dh, $qfn)
            or die $!;

         grep !/^\.\.?\z/, readdir($dh);
      };

      my @children;
      for my $child_fn (@child_fns) {
         my $child_node = _scan("$qfn/$child_fn", $child_fn);
         $size += $child_node->{size};
         push @children, $child_node;
      }

      $node->{children} = \@children;
   }

   $node->{size} = $size;
   return $node;
}
```

Rest of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;    
no warnings 'recursion';

use File::Basename qw( basename );
use JSON           qw( encode_json );

...    

sub scan { _scan($_[0], basename($_[0])) }

print(encode_json(scan($ARGV[0] // '.')));
```

Comment: There are typos in `_` in `-s _;` and `-d _;`.

Comment: @simbabque, I think you mean I should have used `$_` instead of `_`, but you would be wrong. `_` is a handle populated by `stat` and `lstat`. This way, I only do one system call, and I only need to check for error once.

Comment: Changed to stop following symlinks

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I have done it like this:

In the `File::Find` wanted sub `collate_sizes`:

```
my $cursor = $data;
foreach my $element (
    File::Spec->splitdir( $File::Find::dir =~ s/^$starting_path//r ) )
{
    $cursor->{$element}->{name} = $element;
    $cursor->{$element}->{size} += $blocks * $block_size;
    $cursor = $cursor->{$element}->{children} //= {};
}
```

To generate a hash of nested directory names. (The `name` subelement is probably redundant, but whatever).

And then post process it with (using `JSON`):

```
my $json_structure = {
    'name'     => $user,
    'size'     => $data->{$user}->{size},
    'children' => [],
};
process_data_to_json( $json_structure, $data->{$user}->{children} );
open( my $json_out, '>', "homedir.json" ) or die $!;
print {$json_out} to_json( $json_structure, { pretty => 1 } );
close($json_out);


sub process_data_to_json {
    my ( $json_cursor, $data_cursor ) = @_;
    if ( ref $data_cursor eq "HASH" ) {
        print "Traversing $key\n";
        my $newelt = {
            'name' => $key,
            'size' => $data_cursor->{$key}->{size},
        };
        push( @{ $json_cursor->{children} }, $newelt );
        process_data_to_json( $newelt, $data_cursor->{$key}->{children} );
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar, but without the cursor, doing your processing the way you had it already first and iterating over the final structure to create a second one for the JSON processing. But didn't have time to write it up yet.